# Play Scala SBT not showing dependency in Reference Library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I created a new project using Play Scala and Eclipse. Added Squeryl dependency and see that it's been pulled during compile time. Confirmed it's present in .ivy2/cache/org.squeryl directory but eclipse project is not able to pull it up and causing compilation for import.

**build.sbt**

```
name := """registration"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.10" % "0.9.6-RC2"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like squeryl doesn't have a binary readily available for Scala 2.11 yet according to http://www.squeryl.org/getting-started.html

So if you want to use a pre-compiled version of this library you must change your scala version to 2.10.4.

All versions of squeryl available can be found at: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.squeryl

Comment: But that still does not explain why it's not showing up in Eclipse referenced libraries where the jar is present in .ivy2/cache dir.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case using eclipse.

Select Project --> Clean to clean your workspace and build it again if you have not checked "Build Automatically".

[image]

If its still not visible please refresh the package explorer (or just the 'Referenced Library') with F5.